# Change directories size and mount card

Tags: linux, debian, storage

I have a small embedded PC with only 8 GB storage. I have installed Debian 11 with the following sizing:

```
gitlab@pc:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M  6.8M  378M   2% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2  5.7G  5.0G  430M  93% /
tmpfs           1.9G   28K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           385M     0  385M   0% /run/user/1000
gitlab@pc:~$
```

I installed Gitlab CE but as you can see space is running out.

I have a free SD card that I would like to mount and use it as a storage for gitlab data.
How I can mount it and and use it for storage?

Comment: This not nearly enough information. WHAT small embedded PC?  This is kind of the only information needed and the only information you didn't provide.

Comment: this one https://www.electronicsdatasheets.com/manufacturers/solidrun/parts/solidpc-q4

Comment: Why not simply plug in more storage to one of the many USB 3.0 ports?  Why use an SD card and not some beefier storage?  You will need to mount that storage via your [fstab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) or using the `mount` [command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html).  If you have no idea how to accomplish that, your question has nothing to do with your "embedded" device (not really even close to "embedded") and everything to do with Linux administration.